# Android memory automatic cleaning mechanism and garbage collector trigger conditions

Tags: android, memory

I have two problems:

1.What is trigger conditions of LOW_MEMORY and OUT_OF_MEMORY in android memory automatic cleaning mechanism?

I check the reference LOW_MEMORY is done automatically every once in a while, and OUT_OF_MEMORY is conducted in system out of memory. Is this right? If it is right, is the recovery of memory strategy the same？

2.What conditions perform memory of the recovery in android task manager？

The detail condition is testing phone memory 512; the user available memory is 230. The visual inspection is 50M. It can trigger the memory recall in 20M. That is to say 50M and 20M are the stable memory. But sometimes it has not the trigger recycle when the memory less than 3M.
Is the trigger recycle need special condition? Where the trigger recycle code should be put?

Answer (score 0):

In android is each application has fixed memory limit.. it change from device to device... for ex if phone memory is 512.. and app memory will be 30 to 50 mb if your app cross using this memory it will get crash...

onLowMemory is the method in the activity.. it notifier when memory is low... it is like warning .. OUT_OF_MEMORY is exception which you cant handle(catch)..
OUT_OF_MEMORY exception max raise normally when we deal with bitmap...

Garbage collector is available in android also but when we deal with bitmaps it may fail in some cases.. for bitmap we are responsible to recycle..